# Complicated case of type generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I would like to have a type in Java which references itself, in a certain way.

To be exact, I want to have a command class which can have listeners:

```
public abstract class GenericCommand<T> implements Future<T> {
    // ...
    private final List<GenericCommandListener<GenericCommand<T>>> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void addListeners(
            GenericCommandListener<GenericCommand<T>>... listeners) {
        this.listeners.addAll(Arrays.asList(listeners));
    }

    private void onValueAvailable() {
        for (GenericCommandListener<GenericCommand<T>> listener : listeners) {
            listener.onValueAvailable(this);
        }
    }
}
```

A `GenericCommandListener` looks like

```
public interface GenericCommandListener<T extends GenericCommand<?>> {
    public void onValueAvailable(T theCmd);
}
```

The purpose of such a command is to be sent to a device and to produce a result of a certain type.

Now, I want to be able to override my `GenericCommand<T>` so that it implements a special kind of command, maybe a `FooCommand`, which produces a `Double`:

```
public class QueryValueCommand extends GenericCommand<Double> {
}
```

---

Now, I create an instance of this class and want it to accept a `GenericCommandListener<QueryValueCommand>`. But I cannot do so; all I can do is to have it accept a `GenericCommandListener<GenericCommand<Double>>`.

I see the following ways:

1. Do something with `? super` or `? extends` in the listeners definition of the `GenericCommand` class. I tried several combinations, but neither did work, as either the object cannot be put into the list, or the call does not work.
2. Change the definition of the Listener class - but how?
3. Define the `GenericCommand` class in a different way so that it always uses references to listeners of the exactly correct type:

   ```
   public abstract class GenericCommand<T> implements Future<T> {
       private final List<GenericCommandListener<MyExactTypeEvenIfSubclassing>> listeners = ...;
   }
   ```

   so that the `QueryValueCommand` derived from it accepts a `GenericCommandListener<QueryValueCommand>`?

Comment: You need two types here; the type of the ``GenericCommand`` class being used, and the return value of that ``GenericCommand``. In otherwords, the full type specifier should be ``<C extends GenericCommand<T> >``, which ``QueryCommand`` would satisfy for ``T = Double``. In fact, your class definition for ``QueryComannd`` states exactly that; It is not a ``GenericCommand<T>``, it ``extends GenericCommand<T>``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As proposed by aruisdante, the class `GenericCommand` must depends from itself that way :

```
public abstract class GenericCommand<C extends GenericCommand<C, T>, T> implements Future<T> {
    // ...
    private final List<GenericCommandListener<C, T>> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void addListeners(
            GenericCommandListener<C, T>... listeners) {
        this.listeners.addAll(Arrays.asList(listeners));
    }

    private void onValueAvailable() {
        for (GenericCommandListener<C, T> listener : listeners) {
            listener.onValueAvailable((C) this);
        }
    }
}
```

The listener class must also by modified that way :

```
interface GenericCommandListener<C extends GenericCommand<C,T>, T>  {
    public void onValueAvailable(C theCmd);
}
```

Now, you can declare :

```
public class QueryValueCommand extends GenericCommand<QueryValueCommand, Double>
```

and you can write :

```
QueryValueCommand command = new QueryValueCommand();
GenericCommandListener<QueryValueCommand, Double> listener = ...;

command.addListeners(listener);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Alas, I have to have every subclass provide its own name as `C`, and at best make them `final`. This seems redundant to me, and as well always having to provide `C` and `T`. And that cast `(C) this` is not very beautiful as well. But nevertheless, this seems to be the best option, so I implemented it, and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the `GenericCommandListener` like this:

```
  public interface GenericCommandListener<T> {
    public <U extends GenericCommand<T>> void onValueAvailable(U theCmd);
  }
```

Then you should be able to add listeners to your `GenericCommand` class like this:

```
  public abstract class GenericCommand<T> implements Future<T> {
    private final List<GenericCommandListener<T>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public <U extends GenericCommandListener<T>> void addListener(U listener) {
      list.add(listener);
    }
```

Does that help?

Comment: Alas, no, as I want the `onValueAvailable()` functions to receive the command object, not only the value itself.

Comment: `onValueAvailable` does receive the command object `U`, not the the value `T`, as  `U` extends `GenericCommand<T>`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, misread that. But now I cannot create lambdas any longer, as I get now "`Illegal lambda expression: Method onValueAvailable of type GenericCommand<Boolean> is generic`"... somehow I have to plug both types in there...

Comment: Is that on the `addListener` method?

Comment: Yes, I like to use lambdas for listeners. But the other solution seemed to help me.